# Transfering file to remote server behind a gate node with key authentication disabled - and compiling

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-keys

I'm working on a project that requires me to run my code on a remote Unix server, that is not available to connect to directly (you first have to log in to the "gate" node and then  to this server).

What's really bad is that they disabled key authentication, so each time I need to ssh into it, I have to type in my password twice. It's really annoying and I wonder what's the best way to transfer my local modifications of source files to this server, compile and run them without having to provide those passwords so many times.

I have no sudo access to any of those servers (neither to this "gate", nor to this target server). Any ideas on how to make the whole process more efficient?

EDIT: Martin Prikryl provided a great answer below, but it's suitable for Windows and I'm on a Mac :) I guess it might be a good thing to have it documented here also for *NIX systems.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [SSH tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling).

---

WinSCP SFTP client supports [one-hop SSH tunneling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tunneling) natively.

See the [Tunnel page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel) on WinSCP Advanced Site Settings dialog.

[image: Tunnel page]

---

I assume that after you transfer the file, you need to open SSH terminal to compile the file.

You may be able to make use of [WinSCP Console window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console) for that step.

[image]

Alternatively, if you need/want to use a real SSH terminal client, make use of an existing SSH tunnel, created by WinSCP, and connect with PuTTY (or any other SSH client) over it.

In the *Local tunnel port* of WinSCP *Tunnel* page, select a fixed port number (instead of the default *Autoselect*). In PuTTY enter "localhost" to *Host Name* and the selected port in *Port*.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks Martin! I didn't state it properly in a question, but I'm on OS X, so winSCP will not work I guess.. I'll try to emulate what you showed here using SSH. Anyway thanks for such a detailed and well written answer! ;)